# PHP e API - Como conectar com em que usa chave de api autenticaçao via header Breare

Tags: php, api

Pessoal alguem poderia me ajudar, estou precisando consumir uma API que tem forma de autenticaçao via Breare, alguem teria algum exemplo de uma API que faz essa implantaçao?

https://docs.questor.com.br/docs/api

Link da API que deseja me comunicar.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
   <?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'url-api',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Bearer seu-token-aqui'
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).